# List Box item container style , Data Template with Convertor

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

I have List box with data template and convertor embedded to it.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
            <Border x:Name="ListItemBorder" 
                    Margin="0,2,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConvertor}}">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock...

                    <Image ...

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The convertor `BackgroundConvertor` in the above code will add green as background 2 items among 4 item in the list box.

I have applied style to list box when we tap on the item as well.

```
<Style x:Key="ListItemSelectorStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property ="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="ListBoxItem" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ListItemBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#c9ebf2" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ListItemBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#c9ebf2" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ListItemBorder" 
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#e3e8f0">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

When i click on the List item the style is not being applied at all.The style will set background to the selected item.

What i am doing wrong here ?

I am working on Windows Phone 8 application.

Comment: Do you use blend? You can see the different state apply on your listBoxItem. I think, it can help you.

Comment: @MatDev8 i have tried that, if you see the style which i have posted above has different states

Comment: Mouse over state work?

Comment: when you use converter, you have to pass the PROPERTY name based on that value your converter will work. See Christyan's answer. It is helpful to know that what you are trying to achieve by using this converter . Can you share the code?

Comment: @asitis Which code do you want to me share ? because what ever code which i am using is exactly same as i have posted above

Comment: your BackgroundConvertor class codes

Comment: Please see my Edit. i have added my code

Comment: So how you are getting the parameter value . I could not see that you used ConverterParameter with your converter.

Comment: MyObject obj = value as MyObject ; here is how it is

Comment: But where you are passing parameter value? Better you can learn from this link how converter works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter

Comment: @asitis Which parameter value? can i not use it like the one which i have posted ?, its working for me, but only thing is its not applying the style to it, how is that related to Converter class, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: And also What is  Path=PROPERTY ?? her what do i need to add in place of PROPERTY  ???

Comment: PROPERTY is a property which is the object we are passing passing to the Converter class. The value in your converter class gives the value of this PROPERTY . And you can cast it like type of the PROPERTY as you did  MyObject obj = value as MyObject ;

Comment: The difference what i see in the link which you have posted is {Binding Month, Converter={StaticResource Converter1}}" here they have binded Month, but in my case i have not binded to anything

Comment: So you mean its should be like Background="{Binding solidColorBrush Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConvertor}}"

Comment: @asitis are you there ?

Comment: @asitis i tried this Background="{Binding solidColorBrush Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConvertor}}" but now its not applying the background at all

Answer (score 1):

You must modify your VisualState code:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

You must set a Path property when you use Binding and Converter:

```
Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConvertor}, Path=PROPERTY}"
```

Comment: can you please modify mine and paste it , as i am not gettign where to  do the changes that you have suggested

Comment: what is Path=PROPERTY ?? here can you please help me out?